# Disqus SSO, "Your API key is not valid on this domain"

Tags: ios, api, post, single-sign-on, disqus

I'm making API call to `Disqus` from an application in `iOS`. Since my users are authenticated already on my website, I don't want them to authenticate again with Disqus. Disqus has a way to solve this with ***SSO (Single Sign-On)***. I have followed the guide [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/236206-integrating-single-sign-on#sso-script). I have successfully checked the validation on SSO payload and made a sample request in console.

But when I implement the API call from my application I receive :

```
{
    "code":11,
    "response":"Your API key is not valid on this domain"
}
```

I don't know what I do wrong in my code. Could anyone point me to go further ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, could you please post a code snippet how you got this to resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a text box in your Disqus API application settings that lets you specify domains that your public API key is valid on. This error is being thrown because the referrer and host domains don't match any of the ones listed in your application.

Since this is an iOS application, you must set the 'host' and 'referrer' headers to match a domain listed in your application settings. I've confirmed that it works when using this answer:

[How to set Http header Fields in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116192/how-to-set-http-header-fields-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me out! I can post the comment successfully now :D.

Comment: @Phally I am also facing the same issue, could you please post a code snippet how you got this resolved.