# Set httpheader in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering how to set an HTTPHEADER in Objective C.

In PHP, my code looks like :

```
    $headers = array(
            'Sign: '.$sign,
            'Key: '.$key,
            );
     //I send it with curl

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

I tried a few things but I'm not able to create the array that is made by PHP so my request get refused by the server.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Paste in the code that's not working.

Comment: Apple's documentation is really awesome: [setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:)

Comment: See [setAllHTTPHeaderFields:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setAllHTTPHeaderFields:)

Comment: I guess I should read more Apple documentation. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can withe

```
[theRequest setValue:@"value" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Sign"];
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116192/how-to-set-http-header-fields-in-objective-c)

Comment: so check the V sign on the left of my answer :)