# Objective C - HTTP POST REQUEST handle with header and params

Tags: ios, object, authentication, http-post, nsurlsession

I have used POST method to call API with header values and params for body on my application.
but on my back end couldn't able to get my header value to authenticate. even my responce has also invalid user. i have attached my snippet. could you please help me to solve this issue.

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=Message"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL.com/FakeURL"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *authStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName:xxx"];
NSData *authData=[authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *headerValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setValue:headerValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
```

My response has:

```
2017-04-10 16:43:35.635 Testing[5155:172935] ST :200
2017-04-10 16:43:35.636 API_Testing_AeroVoyce[5155:172935] Error :(null)
2017-04-10 16:43:35.638 API_Testing_AeroVoyce[5155:172935] requestReply :invalid user
```

Comment: How are you passing URL?

Comment: @AbilashBNair sorry now i updated the URL
http://myURL.com/FakeURL

Comment: Does it work with POSTMAN?

Comment: Take a look to how to add headers in objective C. I thing that is where you are having your issue in how you are building your request. Try a breakpoint to know the real request you are sending. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5116201/6203030

Comment: Could you show what you do in Postman to replicate it here?

Comment: In post man i had done what i have attached below:
URL : http://myURL.com/FakeURL (POST CALL)
On header : userName:xxx
Body : test=Message (Encrypted Value)  as x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: Is `headerValue` the same has the one you have on POSTMAN? Since you have `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, did you add that header?

Comment: @Larme sorry I tried application/x-www-form-urlencoded before now. but didn't worked

Comment: Could you show screenshots of your POSTMAN (and potentially erase the "confidential parts")? Because, it seems that you are missing something when you try to replicate it with your code. And it's hard to guess which one, without doc or a working sample.

Comment: @Larme sorry for the delay. Eventually My friend fixed this issue.  I was wrongly encrypted and header value was wrong.

This is the issue what i missed to done.
NSDictionary *headers = @{ username: password,
                               @"Content-Type": @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                               @"Cache-Control" : @"no-cache",
                               @"Postman-Token": @"01dbeecf-c6fb-f7fd-1c69-2360131e5452"
                               };

Answer (score 1):

Create single URLrequest for Authorization, URL and content length:

1. You are missing out of content-length in Request HeaderField.

   ```
    - (void)postRequest

    {
      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
       NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test=Message"];
       NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
       NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

       [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL.com/FakeURL"]];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

       NSString *authStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName:xxx"];
       NSData *authData=[authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSString *headerValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];

       [request setValue:headerValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

       [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];


       NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
       NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
           NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
       }];
       [task resume];
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you have added NSURLSessionDataTask to resume.
3. Also check you have enabled **App Transport Security** in info.Plist.

This will help to resolve your issue.

Edit:

Try to do this:

```
 if(data!= nil)
        {
            id JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
            NSLog(@"Response === %@",JSON);
        }
```

Instead of:

**NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];**

Comment: Yes. I've enabled App Transport Security in info.Plist

Comment: I'll try NSURLSessionDataTask

Comment: @Ablilase B nair
Even I called with NSURLSessionDataTask
But i am getting this below issue. I have checked with back end. They told that didn't get your Credentials on your header field.

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.

Comment: Yeah I tried both 
NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

AND

NSDictionary *Json_value = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

I'm getting empty responce when i'm using NSString
and
I'm getting null reswponse when i'm hit NSDictionary

Comment: Just try "NSJSONReadingAllowFragments" instead of NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves

Comment: Yeah Changed to NSJSONReadingAllowFragments. but still i'm getting same @Abilash B Nair

Comment: Are you sending the right value to Authorization as per Webservice requirement?